# How to get rid of periods when splitting string into a list of words using Python?

Tags: python, string, split, text-mining

```py
s = 'I'm all right.'
s.split()

["I'm", "all", "right."]
```

Is there a convenient way to get rid of the periods when splitting a string into a list of words? For example, how can I obtain

```py
["I'm", "all", "right"]
```

in the example above? I want to retain other punctuations such as en dash in *right-out-of-school* and single quote in *I've been there*.

Comment: Assuming that you want the split working across multiple sentences, just do ```re.sub('\.\s*', ' ', s).split()``` where re is regex library

Comment: @EhteshamSiddiqui Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for! You can make it an answer if you want, then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace()` before you split.

```
s = 'I\'m all right.'
out = s.replace('.', '').split()

print(out)
```

Output:

```
["I'm", 'all', 'right']
```

Comment: @paw-in-data Does my answer work for you, or do you prefer the `re.sub()` better?